# How to reflect changes in data base automatically?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I have an ndb entry that can be changed by a rpc call to my app engine app. 
I also have a python web app creating an html site to show the entry.
How do i show the changes when they happen without the need to do refresh page?
I am new at writing server side so i need a hint where to look, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Channels API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview) to push (server-to-client) updates in browser.